# How to open new window from Silverlight Page

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My silverlight application is organized into pages (`System.Windows.Controls.Page`). I use `NavigationService.Navigate` to navigate between pages. I have a requirement to open a new silverlight window on click of a button on a Page to display certain details (from a Dictionary on parent page).

How to create a Silverlight Window and navigate to it from a Page.

How to access the `Dictionary` from the parent Page.

Comment: Sounds like you need a ChildWindow

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use ChildWindow in Silverlight

ref :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow(v=vs.95).aspx
http://childwindow.codeplex.com/